# How to make Surface background transparent (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have such an implemenation

```
Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Transparent),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(2.dp)),
                    border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = showpageColorAgvotBoarder)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp),
                        text = item,
                        style = ShowpageAgvotStyle
                    )
                }
```

the result I get is

[image]

Like entire background is black, however, surface backgroudn is white...

I need just a boarder and background of surface should be transparent (in this case black as entire background is black)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `color = Color.Transparent` parameter instead of `Modifier.background(Color.Transparent)`

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(2.dp)),
    border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Red),
    color = Color.Transparent // This is what you're missing
) {
   Text(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp),
        text = "item",
        color = Color.Gray
   )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The background color of the `Surface` is based on the **`color`** attribute.
By default is:

- `MaterialTheme.colors.surface` (M2)
- `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface` (M3).

Use:

```
Surface(
    color = Color.Transparent,
    //..
) {
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Surface` has a new `color` parameter that dictates the color instead of the modifier.